# How to crop the edges of a rectangle using the form in the layer behind it?

Tags: photoshop-effects, mask, crop

See image attached.[image]
How can I crop the edges of the red rectangles so it follows the rounding of the white bottle behind it?
I'm using Photoshop CS6.
Thanks!

Comment: You have to click and view the image in full screen to see the white bottle form... Sorry I should have put another color than white.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bottle shape as a layer mask for a group containing the colours, and the layer mask will clip the colours inside the group.

Example:[image: Example using layer mask]

A layer group with a layer mask can be repositioned with everything moving along with it - as if it were one element, and the mask will move along with it too. The group can also be resized as a group. There is no need to update the mask at all.  All you need to do is make sure the group is selected before moving or resizing. The `Auto-select: Group` option in the Move tool will help to select the group only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in plenty of ways, some common of them are mention below.

1. Take the selection of the bottle by clicking on bottle layer thumbnail while pressing the ctrl key. Inverse the selection by going to menu Select > Inverse. Now go to each layer and delete them. (Destructive Method)
2. Make the order of bottle to the bottom. Now select all the layers and go to layers panel flyout menu and choose "create clipping mask" or press short key ctrl + alt + G. (Non Destructive and Recommended)
3. However you can also apply layer mask on each layer.

The group layer mask which is mention by another fellow, is only effective when you know you are not going to change the position or resize the bottle. Else every time you change the position or resize you have to update the group layer mask.